# How do I assign an image to JLabel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to assign an png image to `JLabel` .

I tried this code but no image appears [update]:

```
class firstPokemonChoose extends JFrame{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800; //ukuran panjang window
    private static final int HEIGHT = 800; //ukuran lebar window
    JLabel intro, tryImage;

    public firstPokemonChoose(){
        setTitle("Choose Your Pokemon"); //set judul window
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); //set ukuran

        intro = new JLabel("Please choose your first Pokemon", SwingConstants.LEFT);

        java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("torchic.png");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
        tryImage.setIcon(img);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        pane.add(intro);
        pane.add(tryImage);

        setVisible(true); //set windows visible
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        validate();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer, it is working for you?

Comment: @JadChahine already tried both of your suggestions, but it's not working. The frame doesn't appear and it has error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Ok, please create a folder named **Resources** in your project and put your `test.png` image in it, and then use `getClass().getResource("test.png");ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
tryImage .setIcon(image);` and tell me if the error resides or not.

Comment: @JadChahine tried it, but still the same error.

Comment: Please update your question with the full new code and a screenshot of the project directories and the error so I can catch the problem.

Comment: @JadChahine updated it, thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer, I guess that it is working for you.

Comment: @JadChahine it's working! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help you :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recommend to put your images in your project because in this way, your image will be portable with the project and no path should be modify in the code.

If the image is in your project classpath, try this:

```
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/Resources/torchic.png");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
tryImage .setIcon(image);
```

If not, you have to define the absolute path of the image as below:

```
tryImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("path\\torchic.png"));
```

### Update:

You have 2 errors in your code:

The first that you should give the complete path of the image `"/Resources/torchic.png"` and not only `torchic.png`

The second is you are trying to set a icon to the not initialize tryImage `JLabel`

Edit your code as below:

```
class firstPokemonChoose extends JFrame{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800; //ukuran panjang window
    private static final int HEIGHT = 800; //ukuran lebar window
    JLabel intro, tryImage;

    public firstPokemonChoose(){
        setTitle("Choose Your Pokemon"); //set judul window
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); //set ukuran
        intro = new JLabel("Please choose your first Pokemon", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        tryImage = new JLabel(); // initialize the tryImage label
        java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/Resources/torchic.png");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
        tryImage.setIcon(img);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        pane.add(intro);
        pane.add(tryImage);

        setVisible(true); //set windows visible
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        validate();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        firstPokemonChoose firstPokemonChooseInstance = new firstPokemonChoose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why -4 down votes? The above code  is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply to the JLabel an Icon implementation (i.e ImageIcon). You can do it trough the setIcon method, as in your question, or through the JLabel constructor: Try this

```
tryImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
```